# eclipse - is there a "duplicate file to other view" option like notepad++

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Notepad++ has a feature to allow two simultaneous views of the same file in the same instance.

This is useful if you want to view two different regions of a file side-by-side.

Does Eclipse have this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor (Horizontal)' or 'Toggle Split Editor (Vertical)'.

The keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> are shortcuts for these actions. On macOS the keys are <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>